# Is Venice built on poles, piles, or pilings?

Tags: word-choice

Which term should be used to describe the wooden support system of Venice?

Comment: Really? Stone buildings built on pilings? I always just thought it was the worst basement flooding ever.

Answer (score 4):

*Piles* is the most commonly used term (*wooden piles*, to be exact), but *poles* would also work, as does *pilings*. *Stilts*, which isn't one of your options, is an even more precise descriptor:

> **stilt**
>     • each of a set of posts or piles supporting a building above the ground.

The *Oxford American Writers’ Thesaurus* has even more synonyms for *pile* in this meaning:

> **pile** (2. a heavy beam or post driven vertically into the bed of a river, soft ground, etc., to support the foundations of a structure; *a wall supported by timber piles*):
>      • post, stake, pillar, column, support, foundation, piling, abutment, pier, cutwater, buttress, stanchion, upright.

Answer (score 4):

Piles has a specific civil engineer meaning. They are foundation pillars that are driven into the ground - as opposed to columns that are placed on a foundation.

Pilings and piles are mostly interchangeable, pile refers to the actual object, piling to the whole system and the process. So you have a 'pile driver' but a 'piling foundation'.